# List with class created in reflection

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have created a class in run time using reflection. I need to create a List collection of my reflection type. How to do that ?

```
MyClassBuilder MCB = new MyClassBuilder("ReportRecord");
var myclass = MCB.CreateMyProperty(myTable.Columns);
Type TP = myclass.GetType();
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(TP);
List<dynamic> ccc = new List<dynamic>();
```

In the above code I have created a class "ReportRecord" . I need to create collection of ReportRecord that is List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TP);
var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Note, however, that this isn't a `List<dynamic>`; that isn't how "variance" works. You can, however, treat the individual elements as `dynamic` if it suits you:

```
foreach(dynamic item in list) {...}
```

Comment: You're just too fast ;-)

Comment: MyClassBuilder MCB = new MyClassBuilder("ReportRecord");
var myclass = MCB.CreateMyProperty(myTable.Columns);
Type TP = myclass.GetType();
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(TP);
List<ReportRecord> ccc = new List<ReportRecord>();     I need List<ReportRecord>. Dynamic will not work in my case.

Comment: @user3771120 uh - isn't that already in the question?